# Rotation of an object like \ddots in Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the code provided below. The code produces the following picture:

[image]

I want to rotate \ddots, which are showed in red circle, but can not figure out how to do this.

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math,calc,trees,positioning,arrows,fit,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\x =1.8; \y =2.4; \d=1;}

\coordinate[label={[below,yshift=-.1cm]$x$}] (Origin)   at (0,0) circle (.5ex);

\coordinate [label={[below,xshift=0.1cm]$l_1$}](Lone) at ({\x*cos(0)},{\x*sin(0)});
\coordinate [](Lonelong) at ({\y*cos(0)},{\y*sin(0)});

\coordinate [label={[right]$l_2$}](Ltwo) at ({\x*cos(60)},{\x*sin(60)});
\coordinate [](Ltwolong) at ({\y*cos(60)},{\y*sin(60)});

\coordinate [label={[left]$l_3$}](Lthree) at ({\x*cos(120)},{\x*sin(120)});
\coordinate [](Lthreelong) at ({\y*cos(120)},{\y*sin(120)});



\coordinate [label={[above]$l_i$}](Li) at ({\x*cos(180)},{\x*sin(180)});
\coordinate [](Lilong) at ({\y*cos(180)},{\y*sin(180)});

\coordinate [label={[below,xshift=0.3cm, yshift=0cm]$l_{i+1}$}](Liplusone) at ({\x*cos(240)},{\x*sin(240)});
\coordinate [](Liplusonelong) at ({\y*cos(240)},{\y*sin(240)});

\coordinate [label={[below]$l_n$}] (Ln) at ({\x*cos(300)},{\x*sin(300)});
\coordinate [] (Lnlong) at ({\y*cos(300)},{\y*sin(300)});

\coordinate [label={[above,xshift=.2cm,yshift=-.25cm ]$O_n$}](On) at ({\x*cos(330)},{\x*sin(330)});
\coordinate [label={[below,xshift=-.1cm, yshift=.3cm]$O_i$}](Oi) at ({\x*cos(210)},{\x*sin(210)});
\coordinate [label={[below,xshift=.0cm, yshift=.3cm]$O_2$}](O2) at ({\x*cos(90)},{\x*sin(90)});
\coordinate [label={[below,xshift=.1cm, yshift=.3cm]$O_1$}](O1) at ({\x*cos(30)},{\x*sin(30)});


\coordinate [label={[below,yshift=.4cm]\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}](Dots2) at ({\d*cos(150)},{\d*sin(150)});
\coordinate [label={[below,yshift=.1cm]$\dots$}](Dots3) at ({\d*cos(270)},{\d*sin(270)}); % dots



\draw[dotted,pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.5, pattern color=blue](Origin)--(Lone)--(Ln) -- cycle;

\draw[dotted,pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.5, pattern color=blue](Origin)--(Ltwo)--(Lone) -- cycle;


\draw[dotted,pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.5, pattern color=blue](Origin) -- (Ltwo) -- (Lthree) -- cycle;

\draw[dotted,pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.5, pattern color=blue](Origin) -- (Li) -- (Liplusone) -- cycle;

\draw[-](Origin)--(Lone);
\draw[dashed](Lone)--(Lonelong);

\draw[-](Origin)--(Ltwo);
\draw[dashed](Ltwo)--(Ltwolong);

\draw[-](Origin)--(Lthree);
\draw[dashed](Lthree)--(Lthreelong);



\draw[-](Origin)--(Li);
\draw[dashed](Li)--(Lilong);

\draw[-](Origin)--(Ln);
\draw[dashed](Ln)--(Lnlong);

\draw[-](Origin)--(Liplusone);
\draw[dashed](Liplusone)--(Liplusonelong);

\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.5ex);



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `rotate`, e.g. `\coordinate [label={[below,yshift=.1cm,rotate=60]$\dots$}](Dots2) at ({\d*cos(150)},{\d*sin(150)});`.

Comment: If you write it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you a  lot.

Comment: It means that in a moment of anver @Schrödinger's cat  was alive :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating the comment: you can use the rotate key,

```
\coordinate [label={[below,yshift=.1cm,rotate=60]$\dots$}](Dots2) at ({\d*cos(150)},{\d*sin(150)});
```

However, I would like to suggest using loops and other simplifications.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[pattern=north west lines,opacity=0.5, pattern color=blue]
  (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (-60:2) -- (0:2) -- (60:2) -- (120:2) 
  -- (O) -- (-120:2) -- (-180:2) -- cycle;
 \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,label=below:$x$] at (O){};
 \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
 {\draw (60*\X-60+180:2) -- (60*\X-60:2) node[anchor={60*\X+180\ifnum\X<3
 -120\fi}]{$\ell_\X$};
 \draw[dashed] (60*\X-60:2) -- ++(60*\X-60:0.5)
 (60*\X-60+180:2) -- ++(60*\X-60+180:0.5);}
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {\ell_i,\ell_{i+1},\ell_n}
 {\path (\Y*60+120:2)  node[anchor={-60*\Y\ifnum\Y=2 +120\fi}]{$\X$};}
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {O_1,O_2,{},O_i,{},O_n}
  {(-30+60*\Y:2.2) node{$\X$}};
 \path foreach \X in {150,270}  {(\X:1.7) node[rotate=\X-90]{$\dots$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this can be optimized further, and the different loops outside and inside paths are on purpose to illustrate different options.